# Replace function, keep unknown substrings/wildcards

Tags: sql, sql-server, replace, wildcard

I have tried looking for answers online, but I am lacking the right nomenclature to find any answers matching my question.

The DB I am working with is an inconsistent mess. I am currently trying to import a number of maintenance codes which I have to link to a pre-existing Excel table. For this reason, the maintenance code I import have to be very universal. 
The table is designed to work with 2-3 digit number (time lengths), followed by a time unit.

For example, `SERV-01W` and `SERV-03M` .

As these used to be added to the DB by hand, a large number of older maintenance codes are actually written with 1 digit numbers.

For example, `SERV-1W` and `SERV-3M`.

I would like to replace the old codes by the new codes. In other words, I want to add a leading 0 if only one digit is used in the code.

`REPLACE(T.Code,'-[0-9][DWM]','-0[0-9][DWM]')` unfortunately does not work, most likely because I am using wildcards in the result string.

What would be a good way of handling this issue?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming I understand your requirement this should get you what you are after:

```
WITH VTE AS(
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES('SERV-03M'),
                ('SERV-01W'),
                ('SERV-1Q'),
                ('SERV-4X')) V(Example))
SELECT Example,
       ISNULL(STUFF(Example, NULLIF(PATINDEX('%-[0-9][A-z]%',Example),0)+1,0,'0'),Example) AS NewExample
FROM VTE;
```

Instead of trying to replace the pattern, I used `PATINDEX` to find the pattern and then inject the extra `'0'` character. If the pattern wasn't found, so `0` was returned by `PATINDEX`, I forced the expression to return `NULL` and then wrapped the entire thing with a further `ISNULL`, so that the original value was returned.

Comment: Exactly what I needed, and so simple I should have thought of it myself. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I find a simple `CASE` expression to be a simple way to express the logic:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN code LIKE '%-[0-9][0-9]%'
             THEN code
             ELSE REPLACE(code, '-', '-0')
        END)
```

That is, if the code has two digits, then do nothing.  Otherwise, add a zero.  The code should be quite clear on what it is doing.

This is not generalizable (it doesn't add two zeros for instance), but it does do exactly what you are asking for.

Comment: I appreciate your effort, but this would make the query too complex. The query in my first post is part of a longer query. The final line for this column has become `CASE WHEN T.Code LIKE '%SERV%' Then SUBSTRING(ISNULL(STUFF(T.Code, NULLIF(PATINDEX('%-[0-9][DMW]%',T.Code),0)+1,0,'0'),T.Code) WHEN T.Code LIKE '%-OVE%' THEN SUBSTRING(REPLACE(T.Code,'OVE-','OVER-'), CHARINDEX('-OVE', T.Code)+1, 20)
ELSE SUBSTRING(T.Code, CHARINDEX('SAFS', T.Code), 20)
END TaskType`